# Swift rounding down Date seconds to zero

Tags: swift, date

I have a bunch of `Date` objects that I want to perform calculations on, for these calculations I dont need second precision so I am attempting to "zero out" the seconds on my `Date`s.  This all works fine unless the `Date` already has zero seconds in which case Swift decrements the number of minutes by one, e.g 10:30:00 -> 10:29:00.

My code:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var minuteComponent = DateComponents()
minuteComponent.second = 0

let dateDelta = calendar.nextDate(after: date, matching: minuteComponent, matchingPolicy: .nextTime, direction: .backward)
```

I have tried all the matching policies only to get the same result.

This seems odd to me, as the target is already at the required value, though I suspect it is inline with the documentation.

Is this an appropriate way to zero out the seconds while preserving  the higher magnitude components or is there a better way?

Comment: I have considered converting to `TimeInterval` and doing the rounding there and then converting back

Comment: To the user who suggested iOS as a tag; I believe this is a general Swift question, and as such will be rejecting your edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a date formatter, since this cuts off the seconds it will be the same as rounding down.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"

let noSeconds = formatter.date(from: formatter.string(from: someDate))
```

And here is a similar solution using Calendar & DateComponents

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: someDate)
let noSeconds = calendar.date(from: components)
```

Comment: Of the two solution I prefer the second one.  Thanks :)